# Touchscreen no longer working on Dell Latitude 2120

Tags: dell, touchscreen

I initially had Ubuntu 10.10 installed on my netbook, the touch-screen worked completely fine however the distribution upgrade to 12.04 has resulted in my touch-screen no longer working.

lsusb lists many of my other devices properly, but also has this

> Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1cb6:6651

which I believe to be my Touch-screen. Additionally, xinput --list shows the following:

> Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer 
>   (3)]
>     ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave 
>   pointer  (2)]
>     ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad             id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]

I did some digging on the Dell website, the touch-screen itself is an IDEACOM IDC 6651, but there are no linux drivers for available for it from there.

Additionally, lshal shows the following information also related to the touchscreen

> udi =
>   '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_1cb6_6651_noserial_if0'
>   info.linux.driver = 'usbhid'  (string)
>    info.parent =
>   '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_1cb6_6651_noserial' 
>   (string)
>    info.product = 'USB HID Interface'  (string)
>   info.subsystem = 'usb'  (string)
>    info.udi =
>   '/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/usb_device_1cb6_6651_noserial_if0' 
>   (string)
>    linux.hotplug_type = 2  (0x2)  (int)
>   linux.subsystem = 'usb'  (string)
>    linux.sysfs_path =
>   '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0'  (string)   usb.bus_number = 4  (0x4)  (int)
>    usb.can_wake_up = true 
>   (bool)
>    usb.configuration_value = 1  (0x1)  (int)
>   usb.device_class = 0  (0x0)  (int)
>    usb.device_protocol = 0 
>   (0x0)  (int)
>    usb.device_revision_bcd = 4097  (0x1001) 
>   (int)
>    usb.device_subclass = 0  (0x0)  (int)
>   usb.interface.class = 3  (0x3)  (int)
>    usb.interface.number = 0
>   (0x0)  (int)
>    usb.interface.protocol = 0  (0x0)  (int)
>   usb.interface.subclass = 0  (0x0)  (int)
>    usb.is_self_powered =
>   false  (bool)
>    usb.linux.device_number = 2  (0x2)  (int)
>  
>   usb.linux.sysfs_path =
>   '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0' (string)
>   usb.max_power = 100  (0x64)  (int)
>    usb.num_configurations = 1 
>   (0x1)  (int)
>    usb.num_interfaces = 1  (0x1)  (int)
>   usb.num_ports = 0  (0x0)  (int)
>    usb.product = 'USB HID
>   Interface'  (string)
>    usb.product_id = 26193  (0x6651) 
>   (int)
>    usb.speed = 12.0 (12) (double)
>    usb.vendor =
>   'IDEACOM'  (string)
>    usb.vendor_id = 7350  (0x1cb6)  (int)   usb.version = 1.1 (1.1) (double)

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Kernel version `v3.5-rc7-quantal` ( http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5-rc7-quantal/ ). Hopefully it should not change in the final release of 12.10

Installation instructions to use this kernel can be found at ( https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelMainlineBuilds )

Bug page, for reference ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1026174 )